# get real time in datetime picker for vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetimepicker

I am creating a system that will be tracking the documents that will be coming and going. I had fields for the item, received from, received date, referred to and referred date. i am using the date picker for the dates. So the problem is that the date picker is only getting the time from when the system was opened. It should be getting the real time down to the latest second from when the data was saved.

Any idea how?

Thanks

Comment: So when the user clicks the button to save the date (or whatever triggers the save), set the timestamp at that point?  That seems to obvious, so maybe the question is missing something...

Comment: `DateTimePicker` is to allow the user to enter dates and times. It's not a realtime timestamp producer. You do that through your code at runtime.

Comment: Or you could use `TimeOfDay.Hour`, `TimeOfDay.Minute`, `TimeOfDay.Second` to get the actual systemtime Values. It even goes down to `TimeOfDay.Milisecond`